# Sort a list of lists using comparator

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, oop, functional-programming

I am looking at sorting out a list of lists (on ArrayLists), using a comparator. Where the order is largest first. All sublists will always be of the same size.

For example, a list of

```
[[4,5,6], [7,9,10], [4,7,8], [1,2,3], [7,9,12]]
```

This should

```
[[7,9,12], [7,9,10], [4,7,8], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]]
```

I have something like this but only sorts by the first item in each list

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList(4,5,6),
                Arrays.asList(7,9,10), 
                Arrays.asList(4,7,8),
                Arrays.asList(1,2,3), 
                Arrays.asList(7,9,12));

list.sort((l1, l2) -> l2.get(0).compareTo(l1.get(0)));
```

Which produces:

```
[[7, 9, 10], [7, 9, 12], [4, 5, 6], [4, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3]]
```

How can I write a comparator, which sorts by the next item in the list if the item before is equal?

For example, [7, 9, 10], [7, 9, 12] should go onto compare the two 7, then the two 9 and then 10 and 12. For example, [4, 5, 6], [4, 7, 8] should go onto compare the two 4, and tthen the 4 and 7 and stop.

Comment: This is just the same as a lexicographic ordering. How would you implement that with a `List<String>`?

Comment: Create additional method which will iterate over pairs of list elements until it will find non-equal pair. For that pair return result of their comparison. If such pair doesn't exist return 0 which will represent equal lists.

Answer (score 8):

You can define a comparator as such:

```
Comparator<List<Integer>> comparator = (list1, list2) -> {
       for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            int value = Integer.compare(list2.get(i), list1.get(i));
            if (value != 0)
                return value;
       }
       return 0;
};
```

or:

```
Comparator<List<Integer>> comparator = (list1, list2) -> 
IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
         .map(i -> Integer.compare(list2.get(i), list1.get(i)))
         .filter(value -> value != 0)
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(0);
```

Then sort:

```
list.sort(comparator);
```

**Update**:

You can further generalise this by creating a custom generic function that returns a comparator i.e.:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparator<List<T>> comparator(){
       return (o1, o2) -> IntStream.range(0, o1.size())
                                   .map(i -> o2.get(i).compareTo(o1.get(i)))
                                   .filter(value -> value != 0)
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(0);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
List<List<Integer>> integerList = Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList(4,5,6),
                Arrays.asList(7,9,10),
                Arrays.asList(4,7,8),
                Arrays.asList(1,2,3),
                Arrays.asList(7,9,12));

integerList.sort(comparator()); // sort list of integers descending

List<List<String>> stringList = Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList("a","b","c"),
                Arrays.asList("d","e","f"),
                Arrays.asList("g","h","i"));

stringList.sort(comparator()); // sort list of strings descending
```

and so forth...

*Note* - I am using JDK 9+ so I don't know if the type inference is good enough in versions *prior* to JDK 8.

Comment: A raised vote count for the first. A raised eyebrow for the second.

Comment: @Marco13 thanks, I've just had a few mins free time and decided why not make the comparator generic. :)

Comment: I still prefer the list-based method over the stream-based one. Additonally, when generalizing it, relying on the elements being `Comparable` can often be avoided by passing the matching `Comparator` into the method, with `Comparator#naturalOrder` in a method that is specialized for `Comparable` elements. I tried to sketch this idea in my answer.

Comment: For the generic version, I'd rather create a factory function wrapping a parameter `Comparator` rather than relying on `Comparable`.

Answer (score 4):

The sorting order that you are trying to achieve is called [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

In order to compare two lists with this order, you can simply walk through the lists, and compare the corresponding elements. As soon as one comparison yields a non-zero value, this value can be returned. If all elements are equal, zero is returned.

So you can implement the core of this comparison with a generic method:

```
private static <T> int compareLexicographically(
    List<? extends T> list0,
    List<? extends T> list1, 
    Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

Based on this method, you can assemble different sorts of comparators. For `Integer` values (and other types that implement the `Comparable` interface), you can use the [`Comparator#naturalOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) comparator as the last argument. For other types, you can feed in a different comparator. You also always have the option to create a [reversed comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) from that, for example.

Here is an example showing how such a method can be implemented and used for sorting `Integer` objects, `String` objects, or custom objects (here, a simple `Person` class, which is compared by their `getName`).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class LexicographicalComparator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        exampleWithIntegers();
        exampleWithStrings();
        exampleWithPersons();
    }

    private static void exampleWithIntegers()
    {
        List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6), 
            Arrays.asList(7, 9, 10),
            Arrays.asList(4, 7, 8), 
            Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3),
            Arrays.asList(7, 9, 12));

        Comparator<List<Integer>> comparator = lexicographicalComparator();
        list.sort(comparator.reversed());

        System.out.println("Integers, descending:");
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void exampleWithStrings()
    {
        List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("B", "B", "C"), 
            Arrays.asList("C", "B", "B"),
            Arrays.asList("B", "C", "A"), 
            Arrays.asList("A", "C", "B"),
            Arrays.asList("C", "B", "A"));

        Comparator<List<String>> comparator = lexicographicalComparator();
        list.sort(comparator);

        System.out.println("Strings, ascending:");
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void exampleWithPersons()
    {
        class Person 
        {
            String name;
            Person(String name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }
            String getName()
            {
                return name;
            }

            @Override
            public java.lang.String toString()
            {
                return name;
            }
        }

        List<List<Person>> list = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(new Person("B"), new Person("B"), new Person("C")), 
            Arrays.asList(new Person("C"), new Person("B"), new Person("B")),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("B"), new Person("C"), new Person("A")), 
            Arrays.asList(new Person("A"), new Person("C"), new Person("B")),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("C"), new Person("B"), new Person("A")));

        Comparator<List<Person>> comparator = 
            lexicographicalComparator(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
        list.sort(comparator);

        System.out.println("Persons, by name, ascending:");
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }



    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<List<T>> 
        lexicographicalComparator()
    {
        return (list0, list1) -> 
            compareLexicographically(list0, list1, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }

    private static <T> Comparator<List<T>> lexicographicalComparator(
        Comparator<? super T> comparator)
    {
        return (list0, list1) -> 
            compareLexicographically(list0, list1, comparator);
    }

    private static <T> int compareLexicographically(
        List<? extends T> list0,
        List<? extends T> list1, 
        Comparator<? super T> comparator)
    {
        if (list0.size() < list1.size())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (list0.size() > list1.size())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list0.size(); i++)
        {
            T t0 = list0.get(i);
            T t1 = list1.get(i);
            int value = comparator.compare(t0, t1);
            if (value != 0)
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You may still have to think about corner cases. The most important ones are:

- What happens when the lists have different sizes?
- What happens when the lists contain `null` elements?

The first one is currently handled by basically first sorting the lists by their *size*, which may or may not be what you want.

The latter can easily be handled by passing a [`Comparator#nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) or [`Comparator#nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) comparator to the outer method, but you have to be aware of that.

Comment: Can you explain why you wrote Comparable<? super T> instead of just Comparable<T>. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sort the integers by descending order, you first create a comparator that does that, and then chain it together multiple times to create the comparator for the list:

```
Comparator<Integer> intReversed = Integer::compare;
intReversed = intReversed.reversed(); // integer reversed order comparator

// Chain comparators for 3 indices (could also do this in a loop for lists of unknown size)
// Each step compares the extracted element using the given comparator:
Comparator<List<Integer>> comp = Comparator.comparing(l -> l.get(0), intReversed);
comp = comp.thenComparing(l -> l.get(1), intReversed);
comp = comp.thenComparing(l -> l.get(2), intReversed);

list.sort(comp);        
System.out.println(list); // [[7, 9, 12], [7, 9, 10], [4, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Interesting - this is bascially loop unrolling the other options here. I wonder what impact that has on performance.

Comment: What if there are 50 elements?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat you need to loop at some point - why not loop once _outside_ the comparator rather then `n lg(n)` times in each compare operation? I am unsure what the performance implications are, but I see no reason for them not to stand a pretty good chance of being good.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Then you build the comparator in a loop. e.g.: https://ideone.com/KjcOIo Or is that not what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you sort according to the first element of the `Lists` :

```
list.sort((l1, l2) -> l2.get(0).compareTo(l1.get(0)));
```

Either compare all elements but note that if your List don't have the same length, you will have to handle that too.

Or convert the elements of the `List` to `String`s then compare this String :

```
list.sort((l1, l2) -> l2.toString()
                        .compareTo(l1.toString()));
```

This way has the advantage to work even with `List` of `String` of different size.