# Java - Sort list of list LocalTime

Tags: java, list, sorting

I would like to sort a `List<List<LocalTime>>` with `stream()`.

This is what the `List` looks like:

```
[[21:29, 22:29], [16:29, 17:29]]
```

and I would like the list to be like this

```
[[16:29, 17:29], [21:29, 22:29]]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the logic as well? You have a list of list so how do you sort the lists between them?

Comment: Thats a list of list. Not only didnt you include any efforts to solve this yourself, even your requirements are unclear.

Comment: How do you want the lists to be sorted? What would be the desired order be for something like `[[1,3],[2,4]]`? Lexiographical? Average?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a comparator as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49587348/10819573) and perform the sorting.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<List<LocalTime>> list = 
            new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                    new ArrayList<>(List.of(LocalTime.of(21, 29), (LocalTime.of(22, 29)))),
                    new ArrayList<>(List.of(LocalTime.of(16, 29), (LocalTime.of(17, 29))))
            ));

        Comparator<List<LocalTime>> comparator = 
            (list1, list2) -> 
                            IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
                                     .map(i -> list1.get(i).compareTo(list2.get(i)))
                                     .filter(value -> value != 0)
                                     .findFirst()
                                     .orElse(0);
        
        list.sort(comparator);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[16:29, 17:29], [21:29, 22:29]]
```